# Rails - toggle boolean on click of a link

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form

I'm trying to make an app with rails 4 and simple form.

I have models separately called Project, Scope and Finalise. Finalise belongs to Scope. Scope belongs to Project. Project accepts nested attributes for Scope and Finalise. Scope accepts nested attributes for Finalise.

I have an attribute in my Finalise table called :draft.

If a user creates a project and sets :draft as true, then I display a link, which when clicked, will change :draft to false.

I have the following link in my view:

```
  <%= link_to 'Finalise draft', finalise_toggle_draft_path(@project.scope.finalise.id), method: :patch %>
```

I have the following method in my controller:

```
  def toggle_draft
    @finalise = Finalise.find(params[:finalise_id])
    @finalise.draft = false
    @finalise.finalised = Time.now
    @finalise.save
    redirect_to project_path(Project.find(params[:project_id]))
  end
```

When I try this, I get an error that says:  Couldn't find Project without an ID

Does anyone know what I've done wrong?

My routes for finalise are:

```
finalise_toggle_draft PATCH    /finalises/:finalise_id/toggle-draft(.:format)                                                  finalises#toggle_draft
                            finalises GET      /finalises(.:format)                                                                            finalises#index
                                      POST     /finalises(.:format)                                                                            finalises#create
                         new_finalise GET      /finalises/new(.:format)                                                                        finalises#new
                        edit_finalise GET      /finalises/:id/edit(.:format)                                                                   finalises#edit
                             finalise GET      /finalises/:id(.:format)                                                                        finalises#show
                                      PATCH    /finalises/:id(.:format)                                                                        finalises#update
                                      PUT      /finalises/:id(.:format)                                                                        finalises#update
                                      DELETE   /finalises/:id(.:format)                                                                        finalises#destroy
```

Comment: if this error existed in `toggle_draft`, you can print `params` to see what values in it. Of course, you can debug them

Comment: Hi, I'm not sure what your comment means. I get the error when i click on the link. The error says it can't find project without id. I thought that it was looking for an id in the method that I had copied. That's why I'm asking for help to figure this out

Comment: I was telling you how to find why it say that. From your description, your error should is from `@project.scope.finalise.id`

Comment: Hi Abelard, I appreciate that you're trying to help me. I'm afraid I don't know what your suggestion means. Please can you explain it?

Comment: You can add `<% debugger %>` before `<%= link_to ... %>` to check what value  in `@project.scope.finalise.id`